# c# Fill In dataGridView1 from a method in different class?

Tags: c#

I need to populate my dataGridView1 form a method in a different class file.
My `public partial class UpdateS : Form` has the `dataGridView1` and my `public class EWrapperImpl : EWrapper` has the following method with data that I would like to use to populate my datagridview with.

```
    public virtual void position(string account, Contract contract, double pos, double avgCost)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Position. "+account+" - Symbol: "+contract.Symbol+", SecType: "+contract.SecType+", Currency: "+contract.Currency+", Position: "+pos+", Avg cost: "+avgCost);
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Symbol";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "SecType";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Position";

        string[] row = new string[] { "" + contract.Symbol, "" + contract.SecType, "" + pos };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

How can I accomplish this? thank you in advance.

Comment: Firstly, this method (when coded properly) will only create one line. You probably dont what to intialize (create columns) and populate with just that record.

Comment: The way that 'position' method is currently, you can't reuse it to populate your datagridview. You will have to change the signature of the method to accept a datagridview to populate OR return an array of rows and then assign to your datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the DataGridView by reference from **UpdateS** to **EWrapperImpl** then populate it from there.

```
public virtual void position( ref DataGridView dataGridView1, string account, Contract contract, double pos, double avgCost)
{
    // ...
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. Could you give me a little more code? I have been playing around with this but cant get it to work.

Comment: I'm getting this error "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0535 'EWrapperImpl' does not implement interface member 'EWrapper.position(string, Contract, double, double)' IB_CSharp_RealTime_WinForms_CS C:\Users\toto\Desktop\C#\IB_CSharp_RealTime_WinForms_CS\IB_CSharp_RealTime_WinForms_CS\EWrapperImpl.cs 13 Active
"